# Apache2 is missing conf.d file

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, apache, mod-tile

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/MarcHuang1/osm-installation-en) about how to create my own tiles and got stuck on slide 20. I am trying to tell my web server about my mod_tile installation. However the folder `/etc/apache2` doesn't have a `conf.d`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is Apache running ~ do you get an "It Works!" statement when you browse to http://localhost?

Comment: Yeah it works. The folder just doesn't exist in my apache configuration for some reason.

Comment: The name of the folder is not important, different implementations of Apache are built differently, the important thing is that it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it the following way:

Go to the folder mods-available

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
```

Create the file here

```
sudo touch mod_tile.load
```

Edit the file

```
sudo gedit mod_tile.load
```

add this line to the file

```
LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so
```

Tell apache to use the mod

```
sudo a2enmod tile
```

Restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```